# javascript close audio stream and remove mic icon from tab

Tags: javascript

I got a page which uses user microphone with the following code:

```
setup = async () => {

    this.socket.current.emit('startGoogleCloudStream', '');
    context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)({
        // if Non-interactive, use 'playback' or 'balanced' // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContextLatencyCategory
        latencyHint: 'interactive',
    })
    processor = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1)
    processor.connect(context.destination)
    context.resume()

    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    globalStream = stream
    input = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
    input.connect(processor)

    processor.onaudioprocess = (e) => {
        this.microphoneProcess(e)
    }
}

microphoneProcess = (e) => {
    let left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)
    let left16 = downsampleBuffer(left, 44100, 16000)
    this.socket.current.emit('binaryData', left16)
}
```

When mic is used the following icon is displayed in the tab:

[image: pic]

I need to create somekind a stop button and when it is clicked - audio stops and this icon disappears. How can I do that? Is it possible not to request user permissions for audio when audio stream is created again on the same page?

Thank you.